# Using range function for assigning a string to variable

Tags: python

How can I create an empty string and assign it to the variable "Letter". Then using range, write code such that when I run code, "Letter" has 5 `'a'`  i.e. `"aaaaa"`

Comment: What's wrong with just `'a' * 5`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
Letter=""
for i in range(5):
    Letter+="a"
print(Letter)
```

Comment: Also, the variable's first letter should not be capitalized. It should be `letter`

Comment: what's the problem with capitalizing the first character in the variable?

Comment: It's a best practice in python to name variables in small letters, if you use capital letters for the first character, your code will work, but it will be confusing when you work on bigger projects. Capital letters are generally only used for naming classes